# SQL: Getting pairs of entities having at least N other entity in common

Tags: sql

Taking the basic database schema:

```
posts,
  - id,   -- PK
  - title
tags,
  - id,   -- PK
  - value
```

with a **many-to-many relationship between posts and tags**, thus a posts_tags linking table:

```
posts_tags
  - post_id,   -- FK linked to posts.id
  - tag_id,   -- FK linked to tags.id
```

I'd like to get the **pairs of tags** (e.g tag "sport" AND "international") which **have at least N posts in common**. How to do that in SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    pt1.tag_id,
    pt2.tag_id
FROM
    posts_tags pt1
JOIN
    posts_tags pt2 ON
        pt1.post_id = pt2.post_id
        AND pt1.tag_id < pt2.tag_id
GROUP BY
    pt1.tag_id,
    pt2.tag_id
HAVING
    COUNT(*)>10
```

Comment: You should probably add `WHERE pt1.tag_id < pt2.tag_id` so pairs only occur once and tags are not paired with themselves.